# Route TestKit in asynchronous ScalaTest

Tags: scala, asynchronous, scalatest, akka-http, akka-testkit

I am switching synchronous [ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.org/) tests of some Akka HTTP code to [AsyncFunSpec](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/async_testing). Is there a simple way to make [Akka TestKit](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/testkit.html) tests asynchronous, as well? I am talking about code like:

```
Get("/test") ~> testRoute ~> check {
    responseAs[String] shouldEqual "Fragments of imagination"
}
```

What I would basically need is a version of `check` which returns a `Future` instead of calling `await`. Or a helper function which converts a `HttpRequest` like `Get("/test")` into a [`RequestContext`](http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.4.5/akka/http/scaladsl/server/RequestContext.html) so that I can apply the route to it.

Comment: What people seem to be doing is globally set a timeout stretch factor so that tests don't timeout: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/testing.html#accounting-for-slow-test-systems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using something like this:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.client.RequestBuilding.Get
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route

val handler = Route.asyncHandler(testRoute)

for {
  response <- handler(Get("/test"))
  strict <- response.entity.toStrict
  res <- strict.toString shouldEqual "Fragments of imagination"
} yield res
```